# I want to save a NSDictionary in PHImageManager.requestImageData in swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to save a NSDictionary to another NSDictionary, but it always not work. My code is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: self.detailPhoto, options: nil, resultHandler:{
        (data, responseString, imageOriet, info) -> Void in
        let imageData = data! as NSData
        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, nil) {
            let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary

            self.imageDic = imageProperties
        }
    })

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if self.imageDic == nil {
        print("nil")
    } else {
        print("not nil")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (self.imageDic?.count)!
}
```

The "imageProperties" is ok and saves values well, but the "imageDic" cannot save anything. It always print nil. And the return is not work.

I am a new one in swift programming so I am getting pretty confused. Someone could explain how they changed it to Swift that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please read something about [How to Create and Configure a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html). Your approach is quite wrong.